# Is there any tool or IDE available for creating wso2 human task flow or do we need to do manually

Tags: eclipse, wso2, bpel, business-process-management, business-process

Please suggest how can I create human task and its corresponding UI for WSO2 BPS server. The documentation given in WSO2 website contains only information about how to use it, but I did not get any documentation for Human task creation. 
Also let me know, Is it possible to create human task in WSO2 eclipse IDE, if not then which IDE or technology I can use for human task creation.
Please comment ASAP as I need to give Demo for BPEL workflow with human intervention using WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

Creating humantasks for WSO2 Business Process Server is explained at [[1]](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Writing+a+Human+Task+Artifact). A sample bpel process and a humantask is explained at [[2]](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Claims+Approval+Task+Sample). 
WSO2 Business Process Server provides a humantask client API. so that you can even implement an external task UI as explained in [[3]](http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-implement-your-own-task-ui-on.html) & [[4]](http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/12/approval-based-user-registration.html).

[1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Writing+a+Human+Task+Artifact) http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Writing+a+Human+Task+Artifact

[2](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Claims+Approval+Task+Sample) http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS300/Claims+Approval+Task+Sample

[3](http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-implement-your-own-task-ui-on.html) http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-implement-your-own-task-ui-on.html

[4](http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/12/approval-based-user-registration.html) http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/12/approval-based-user-registration.html

I would recommend you to try out this as the various [functionalities](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS310/BPS+Features) available with WSO2 process server and supporting standards.

Thanks

Thilini

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to the BPEL world. I warmly recommend you try out Intalio|bpms.

It is using Apache ODE for process execution, coupled with a rich Designer tool allowing you to create graphically complex business processes and deploy them in a click to the server.

Full disclosure, I am the Chief Architect of Intalio.